# Hyperparameter optimization in pytorch (currently with sklearn GridSearchCV)

Tags: pytorch, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv, optuna, ray-tune

I use this([link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html)) pytorch tutorial and wish to add the grid search functionality in it ,sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV ([link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/skorch-dev/skorch/blob/master/notebooks/Basic_Usage.ipynb#Usage-with-sklearn-GridSearchCV)), in order to optimize the hyper parameters. I struggle in understanding what X and Y in gs.fit(x,y) should be; per the documentation ([link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)) x and y are supposed to have the following structure but I have trouble figuring out how to get these off the code. The output of the class PennFudanDataset returns img and target in a form that does not align with the X, Y I need.
Are n_samples, n_features within the following block of code or in the tutorial’s block regarding the model?

```
fit(X, y=None, *, groups=None, **fit_params)[source]

Run fit with all sets of parameters.
```

**Parameters**

```
Xarray-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.

yarray-like of shape (n_samples, n_output) or (n_samples,), default=None
Target relative to X for classification or regression; None for unsupervised learning.
```

Is there something else we could use instead that is easier to implement for this particular tutorial? I’ve read about ray tune([link](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/)), optuna([link](https://optuna.org/)) etc. but they seem more complex than that. I am currently also looking into scipy.optimize.brute([link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute)) which seems simpler.

**PennFundanDataset class:**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image


class PennFudanDataset(object):
def __init__(self, root, transforms):
    self.root = root
    self.transforms = transforms
    # load all image files, sorting them to
    # ensure that they are aligned
    self.imgs = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "PNGImages"))))
    self.masks = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "PedMasks"))))

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # load images ad masks
    img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "PNGImages", self.imgs[idx])
    mask_path = os.path.join(self.root, "PedMasks", self.masks[idx])
    img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
    # note that we haven't converted the mask to RGB,
    # because each color corresponds to a different instance
    # with 0 being background
    mask = Image.open(mask_path)
    # convert the PIL Image into a numpy array
    mask = np.array(mask)
    # instances are encoded as different colors
    obj_ids = np.unique(mask)
    # first id is the background, so remove it
    obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

    # split the color-encoded mask into a set
    # of binary masks
    masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]

    # get bounding box coordinates for each mask
    num_objs = len(obj_ids)
    boxes = []
    for i in range(num_objs):
        pos = np.where(masks[i])
        xmin = np.min(pos[1])
        xmax = np.max(pos[1])
        ymin = np.min(pos[0])
        ymax = np.max(pos[0])
        boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

    # convert everything into a torch.Tensor
    boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
    # there is only one class
    labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
    masks = torch.as_tensor(masks, dtype=torch.uint8)

    image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
    area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
    # suppose all instances are not crowd
    iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)

    target = {}
    target["boxes"] = boxes
    target["labels"] = labels
    target["masks"] = masks
    target["image_id"] = image_id
    target["area"] = area
    target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

    if self.transforms is not None:
        img, target = self.transforms(img, target)

    return img, target

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.imgs)
```

Comment: You can use `skorch` ([here](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch)) for GridSearchCV interoperability with PyTorch.